# Wordpress shortcode problems with css hover

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, shortcode

I am trying to solve an issue with CSS on my shortcode.

You can see it here in action:

http://www.mariovital.com/jose-ollin/sample-page

and the shortcode code:

```
// Add Shortcode
function servicos_shortcode( $atts ) {

// Attributes
extract( shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'posicao' => '',
        'icon' => 'default.png',
        'titulo' => 'O Serviço',
        'link' => '',
    ), $atts )
);

// Code
return '
<div class="span3 fp-'.$posicao.'">
    <div class="widget-front">
      <div class="thumb-wrapper tc-holder">
        <a class="round-div" href="'.$link.'" title="'.$titulo.'"></a>
        <img src="'.$icon.'" alt="'.$servico.'">
      </div> 
      <!-- /.widget-front -->
     <h4>'.$titulo.'</h4>
    </div> 
</div> ';

}

add_shortcode( 'servicos', 'servicos_shortcode' );
```

The problem is with the hover selector you can see on my test page. I really don't know what is wrong with the CSS code.

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: You say there is a CSS issue and mention hover... But there is no CSS code.  If it is a CSS issue then we need to see the CSS.

Comment: i cant post all the css elements here, but u can see with firebug or similar on your borwser ( firefox, chrome ).

the problem its doing the hover under all the round options at the same time .

Comment: Hey I just posted an answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @aniskhan001  i tryng on fiddle here is the link [http://jsfiddle.net/mvital/Kg9X8/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want the hover effect **should happen to a particular div** when it hovers by users. And it **should not happen to all of those** divs at once. So here goes the solution -

On your CSS, you have setup hover effect for both `<article>` and `<div class="widget-font">`

```
.widget-front.hover .round-div,
article.hover .round-div {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
  -o-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

But if you don't want the hover effect should affect all the divs inside the `article`. So, just remove the `article.hover .round-div` from CSS and your final snippet should looks like this -

```
.widget-front.hover .round-div {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
  -o-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
}
```

**EDIT :**

I just have a look at your code. You still have `article.hover .round-div` on your CSS code. If the CSS is generating externally and you are not able to change that, you can add this following code at the end -

```
article.hover .round-div {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
```

Comment: hi @aniskhan001

still with the same issue with the over, i made the changes that you post above, but the problem persist still **show the hover effect on all divs **

Comment: If you are not able to edit the CSS file by hard coding you can try another approach. Please check the update of my answer.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/mvital/Kg9X8/]  try here @aniskhan001 i belive that i got every css defined ..

Comment: The `.hover` class is added when user hover over a div. It was done done by JS on your site. You didn't included any JS in this fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mvital/96aCm/1/ jquery 1.11 its loading on framework/Extensions